# Application conftest stopped unexpectedly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-15.10

I have set up phpfarm so that I can use multiple versions of PHP interpreter on my system. This work really good but now I am getting crash reports on each and every system start.

Seems like my ubuntu 15.10 tries to start `conftest` which does not exist (anymore?). This error repeats for every PHP version installed.

Who/what is trying to execute `conftest` can't find any reference of this file.

Here is the crash report (excerpt, please ask if more is needed):

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Wed Dec 30 11:34:06 2015
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 15.10
ExecutablePath: /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.29/conftest
ExecutableTimestamp: 1451471646
ProcCmdline: ./conftest
ProcCwd: /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.29
ProcEnviron:
 TERM=xterm-256color
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE=C
ProcMaps:
 00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 36461534                           /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.29/conftest
 00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fc:01 36461534                           /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.29/conftest
 00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fc:01 36461534                           /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.29/conftest
 7f316d94c000-7f316db0c000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 37748784                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
 7f316db0c000-7f316dd0c000 ---p 001c0000 fc:01 37748784                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
 7f316dd0c000-7f316dd10000 r--p 001c0000 fc:01 37748784                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
 7f316dd10000-7f316dd12000 rw-p 001c4000 fc:01 37748784                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.21.so
 7f316dd12000-7f316dd16000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f316dd16000-7f316dd1f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 37748772                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.21.so
 7f316dd1f000-7f316df1e000 ---p 00009000 fc:01 37748772                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.21.so
 7f316df1e000-7f316df1f000 r--p 00008000 fc:01 37748772                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.21.so
 7f316df1f000-7f316df20000 rw-p 00009000 fc:01 37748772                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.21.so
 7f316df20000-7f316df4e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f316df4e000-7f316df72000 r-xp 00000000 fc:01 37748770                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
 7f316e151000-7f316e154000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f316e16f000-7f316e171000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7f316e171000-7f316e172000 r--p 00023000 fc:01 37748770                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
 7f316e172000-7f316e173000 rw-p 00024000 fc:01 37748770                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.21.so
 7f316e173000-7f316e174000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fff7a5cb000-7fff7a5ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7fff7a5f1000-7fff7a5f3000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
 7fff7a5f3000-7fff7a5f5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```